# What is the correct way to integrate wordpress with another php application?

Tags: themes, customization

I want to integrate wordpress blog with another php application so both will have same theme and when i do changes in wordpress menu or wordpress sidebar, the changes will apply automatically to the other php application pages.

Comment: What kind of other php application are you running?
I can imagine running some external php stuff inside wordpress, but I can't imagine the other way round. Could you be more specific?

Comment: My website is in php and I want to integrate a wordpress blog with it but I want the wordpress theme to be the theme of all the website not just the blog. Also, I want to control menus and widgets with wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you'd need to insert your code to the existing WordPress site. please follow this logic:

1. create a WP install.
2. create a custom template for your app.
3. migrate the PHP code and see that it works.

good luck!